# Automator/Applescript + shell script: grab parent folder name

Tags: shell, applescript

I have a Automator workflow that utilizes this shell script to grab the name of the directory hosting the file running through this workflow. Later I place that directory name as comment for the file.

```
for f in "$@"
do
    filepath=$(dirname "$f")
    dirname=$(basename "$filepath")

echo "$dirname"
done
```

Whenever I throw multiple files at it though, the directory name gets reflected not once (as I would like to) but times however many files I dropped at it. This then later adds the same comment that many times.

How do I fix that?

[image]

EDIT:
I want to try eliminate Automator and go with Applescript + Shell alone.
How do I have the shell return the directory name? Right now it just gives me `$dirname` in the dialog...

```
on adding folder items to theWatchedFolder after receiving theDetectedItems
    set dirName to do shell script "for f in '$@'
do
    filepath=$(dirname '$f')
    dirname=$(basename '$filepath')

echo '$dirname'
done"
    display alert dirName
end adding folder items to
```

Comment: It has to do that since, if you pass ir multiple foldernames, each one could potentially have a different parent. Surely? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: My whole approach may be wrong then... What I'd like is each file to be treated separately and assigned its unique comment (only its parent folder name). But I'd like to have the ability to batch files where I can drop all of them at the workflow and for each to behave as described here. ...What's my alternative then?

Comment: I revised my approach to exclude Automator and opt for Applescript instead...

Answer (score 0):

```
on adding folder items to thisFolder after receiving added_items
    repeat with aFile in added_items
        tell application "Finder"
            set parentpath to POSIX path of (parent of (aFile) as string)
            set comment of aFile to parentpath
        end tell
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

Comment: Of course, since this appears to be a folder action, it's going to add the exact same path to every file... are you looking for the path they were at before they were moved to the folder? That would be tough... may require a time machine...

Answer (score 0):

I would go with an Applescript droplet.

Save this code as an Application.

When you drop files onto it from a single dir or multiple, it will comment each file with it's own original dir.

Then move the file to the listed move folder.

```
property moveFolder : "Macintosh HD:Users:USERNAME:fooDIR:"

on open theseFiles

    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theseFiles
        set this_item to item i of theseFiles
        tell application "Finder"
            set parentpath to POSIX path of (parent of (this_item) as string)
            set comment of this_item to parentpath
        end tell
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"

        move theseFiles to moveFolder
    end tell
end open
```

You could use a `choose` command to choose where to move the files instead of hard coding but the files may not be always handed of to the droplet in a single batch even though thats how you dropped them on to it. This means the `choose dialog may display multiple times on whats seems a single run.

But the above hopefully gives you a starting place.